# How to add a subtitle to a beamer document

Tags: beamer, titles

Hey I've tried to add a subtitle in document class like this

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{title}
\subtitle{subtitle}
\author{name}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
%content
\end{document}
```

But it gives me errors. please someone help me to add a subtitle to my document.

Comment: This works fine for me if you add `\maketitle` to your document (instead of `%content`). By the way, you need to typeset at least something (that is, have something the generates output) within the `document` environment. Does this work for you?

Comment: yeah I used \maketitle but it didn't work. \title{title \\ subtitle} didn't work either..

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about the error you encounter? What error message do you get? Do you get any output at all?

Comment: `\documentclass{beamer}
\title{title}
\subtitle{subtitle}
\author{name}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}` yields no error. You may check your beamer version and/or specify your question by adding the error log

Comment: Maybe it helps if you remove the auxiliary files first and then compile with a `\maketitle` command.

Comment: I want to create a sub title and When I use the title and tries to make a newline by using "\\" it gives me error "! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end."  I want to create a sub title apart from the main title. hope you got the problem

Comment: @ArunaSujith: But now you're switching documentclass from `beamer` to `report`. The documentclass is important in the choice of solution, since it may influence many of the basic usages you're after. Please provide a *complete* yet *minimal* document showing exactly what you've tried, and what you're after. Do so via an [edit to your post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/44947/edit). Before doing so, please read what is meant by a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} \title
{\begin{huge}
\textbf{Cloud Computing}
\end{huge}}
\author{
        K.P.A.S. Karunarathna \\ \        Index No :  *****\\ \        Registration No : *******\\ \        ********@gmail.com ,  +94 ****** \\ \        \textbf{Supervisor : Dr.*******} \\  \\           
        University of ************ \\ \        Sri Lanka        
}
\date{\today}   here is the document and I want to enter a subtitle called "Literature Survey". But I'm unable to do it.

Comment: @ArunaSujith This is not what we're looking for. Please edit your initial question and insert the minimal example there. It should be a complete LaTeX document, including `\documentclass` command and `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: You don't add any content to this document. use `\maketitle` after `begin{document}`. see this code https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bxnHtnK5hG/ and this output https://pasteboard.co/HdNtDhe.png

Comment: I didn't see that my approach is added earlier.

Comment: Googling for "latex beamer subtitle" (I wanted to know how to put a subtitle in a beamer presentation) brought me here immediately, and moreover, this page gave me the answer. It also gives the answer to the OP's question: you have to put something in your document.
Given that the page is useful and visible and the question has been answered, perhaps one might consider to reopen the question and post an answer?